# plotting the data from csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

5.30-420462 |          100 | SAT-Synergy-gen2 |
| 5.30-42 |           92 | Scale            |
| 5.30-423 |           90 | Scale            |
| 5.30-420 |           76 | Scale            |
| 5.30-420462 |           85 | Scale            |
| 5.30-4205 |           88 | Scale            |
| 5.30-420664 |           88 | Scale            |
| 5.30-421187 |           90 | Scale            |
| 5.30-421040 |           93 | Scale            |
| 5.30-421225 |          100 | Scale-DCS-VET    |
| 5.30-421069 |          100 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-420664 |            0 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-421040 |          100 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-420693 |          100 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-420543 |           88 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-421225 |           76 | UPT_C7000        |
| 5.30-420462 |           96 | UPT_C7000        |

The above is the data from the database in the csv file. I want to use the first and second  columns for plotting the graph and 3rd column will be the reference to 1st and 2nd column. Can someone help me to plot these data using pandas or any module?

Comment: Is there a specific technical issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried but doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `matplotlib` for plotting data. And reading the data in with `pandas`. Then you could try set label and other stuff.
Reading in the data from your file -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Plotting the data -> https://datatofish.com/plot-dataframe-pandas/